# Is flatulence/gas comprised of methane? Is it flammable? What about burps/belching?

Tags: flatulence-gas-fart, gut-microbiota-flora, fermentation

Recently, I read that in a surgery, flatulence (and its methane qualities) emitted by the patient was the culprit for a fire igniting when it came in contact with the surgical laser. http://www.foxnews.com/health/2016/11/01/hospital-report-blames-patients-fart-for-surgical-fire.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20foxnews%2Fmost-popular%20(Internal%20-%20Most%20Popular%20Content)

Are all flatulence/gasses passed comprised of methane (and potentially flammable)? Or is that dependent on the food we eat and the type of gut-microbiota we have to break down and digest the food? Or how long the food ferments in our GI tract?

Is burpring/belching comprised of the same elements? Or is that mainly trapped air? I'm assuming that it wouldn't have methane or flammable qualities, correct?

P.S. It isn't my intention to have a juvenile discussion about this (I know this is a social taboo -- not proper etiquette), but I sincerely would like to know the answer to this, and I apologize if this offends anyone.